# How to define a C++ iterator that skips tombstones

Tags: c++, iterator, tombstone

I am implementing a container that presents a map-like interface.  The physicals implementation is an `std::vector<std::pair<K*, T>>`.  A `K` object remembers its assigned position in the vector.  It is possible for a `K` object to get destroyed.  In that case its remembered index is used to zero out its corresponding key pointer within the vector, creating a tombstone.

I would like to expose the full traditional collection of iterators, though I think that they need only claim to be `forward_iterator`s (see next).

I want to be able to use range-based for loop iteration to return the only non-tombstoned elements.  Further, I would like the implementation of my iterators to be a single pointer (*i.e.* no back pointer to the container).

Since the range-based for loop is pretested I think that I can implement tombstone skipping within the inequality predicate.

```
bool operator != (MyInterator& cursor, MyIterator stop) {
    while (cursor != stop) {
        if (cursor->first)
            return true;
        ++cursor;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach?  If yes, is there a simple way for me to override the inequality operator of `std::vector`'s iterators instead of implementing my iterators from scratch?

If this is not a reasonable approach, what would be better?

Comment: Make's no sense to me. What does where the iterator stops in a range based loop have to do with skipping tombstones? I think you should just implement an iterator that does skip tombstones, and then everything else just falls into place.

Comment: I'm not sure you need a custom iterator. If your only goal is to skip elements satisfying some property, then I think you're looking for [`filter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view).

Comment: Don't adjust in the comparison operator. `operator++` is where you should move the iterator to the next non-tombstone item. And, no, you can't override parts of std::vector's iterators; you have to write your own from scratch. It's not hard to do. Each iterator can hold a `std::vector::iterator` (not your own pointer) and operate appropriately on that.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo My goal is to provide a more efficient, drop-in replacement for an expensive, elaborate framework in which - rare but real - object destruction deletes elements from maps.  My users expect to iterate over these map (using range-based for) and retrieve only live mapping.  This idiom is widely used in our codebase.  Clients would not happily accept needing to introduce `filter`, or more likely, adding their own check for a null key after debugging a `SEGV`.  Bottom line: if it is not a drop-in replacement then my effort will have failed.  It would likely get rejected during review.

Comment: @PeteBecker I understand the intuitive expectation that comparison is side-effect-free while `operator++` is not.  That said, I cannot see how to implement a single pointer iterator that skips tombstone within `operator++`.  The skipping loop needs access to both the  cursor and end iterators.  Comparison is the only point where that occurs.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a reasonable approach?

No. (Keep in mind that `operator!=` can be used outside a range-based for loop.)

- Your operator does not accept a `const` object as its first parameter (meaning a `const vector::iterator`).
- You have undefined behavior if the first parameter comes after the second (e.g. if someone tests `end != cur` instead of `cur != end`).
- You get this weird case where, given iterators `a` and `b`, it might be that `*a` is different than `*b`, but if you check if `(a != b)` then you find that the iterators are equal and then `*a` is the same as `*b`. This probably wrecks havoc with the multipass guarantee of forward iterators (but the situation is bizarre enough that I would want to check the standard's precise wording before passing judgement). Messing with people's expectations is inadvisable.
- There is no simple way to override the inequality operator of `std::vector`'s iterators.

---

> If this is not a reasonable approach, what would be better?

You already know what would be better. You're just shying away from it.

- Implement your own iterators from scratch. Wrapping your vector in your own class has the benefit that only the code for that class has to be aware that tombstones exist.

  - *Caveat:* Document that the conditions that create a tombstone also invalidate iterators to that element. (Invalid iterators are excluded from most iterator requirements, such as the multipass guarantee.)

OR

- While your implementation makes a poor `operator!=`, it could be a fine update or check function. There's this little-known secret that C++ has more looping structures than just range-based for loops. You could make use of one of these, for example:
  `for ( cur = vec.begin(); skip_tombstones(cur, vec.end()); ++cur ) {`
      `auto& element = *cur;`
  where `skip_tombstones()` is basically your `operator!=` renamed. If not much code needs to iterate over the vector, this might be a reasonable option, even in the long term.